# need a DAX for a 15 day period stock return

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power BI file including close prices of some stocks, to analyze the return of each stock i need to have a last-15 day period return. I tried to do some DAX but so far no success! the code i wrote is as follows:

```
15 Day % return = 
VAR curdate = MAX(Stocks[Date])
VAR predate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Stocks[Date]),
        DATEADD(Stocks[Date], -15, DAY)
    )
VAR priceinPredate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Stocks[Close]),
        Stocks[Date] = predate
    )
RETURN     
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(priceinPredate)),
        DIVIDE(
            MAX(Stocks[Close])priceinPredate,
            MAX(Stocks[Close])
        )
    )
```

if you help me correct the code I would be so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

After an appropriate, human readable formatting of the DAX expression (see above) the error is obvious: The numerator of the DIVIDE function

```
MAX(Stocks[Close])priceinPredate
```

doesn't make any sense and this is what throws the error. Btw., the textbook formula to calculate price returns is actually

```
DIVIDE(
    MAX(Stocks[Close]) - priceinPredate,
    priceinPredate
)
```

Comment: Peter, thanks for detecting the error but how can I fix this to get my desired result? since I have just started learning DAX